# how can I show data in table format in bot message?

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, bots, adaptive-cards

I  am fetching data from the SharePoint list which will return multiple column and rows.
Is there any way to show data of the message in a tabular format without using adaptive cards.
I want to show a table on the bot.

Comment: You should provide some code and even more details on your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in plain text, so you'd need to look at another options. Adaptive Cards is one way, but you mention that you don't want to do that. Perhaps you can send the person a link to a page where you show the data? Alternatively, you could generate an image dynamically and send it as an "image" attachment.

Comment: can we add HTML in bot's message

Comment: no, no HTML support in regular messaged. Adaptive Cards offer *limited* markdown support (see here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/authoring-cards/text-features#markdown), but no Tables (see on that link)